# Intent Filter for YouTube is acting goofy

Tags: android, filter, youtube, android-intent

I just can't get visiting YouTube on the browser to launch my app. Must be because of AJAX / redirects. This works for Flickr and other websites for me but not for YouTube.

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="youtube.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*.youtube.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Is there any way doing this?

Comment: Works when going to youtube.com, m.youtube.com still doesn't work, even when I write that on the android:host attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The following `intent-filter` works for me on 4.0+:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSEABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="*.youtube.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/watch" />
</intent-filter>
```